# Create directory in access

Tags: xml, ms-access

I am using MS access to output some XML files based on my table data.

In order for this to happen, I need my script to create the directory if it does not exist.

The directory should be based in a field in the table. Right now it is using a field 'category'.

```
If Len(Dir("P:\" + rs!Category, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir "P:\" + rs!Category
End If
```

It seems to work, but gives me an error. (runtime error 13 type mismatch)

Answer (score 1):

`Dir(Null, vbDirectory)` throws error 13, *"Type mismatch"*.

Make sure `rs!Category` is not Null when you call `Dir()` because `"P:\" + Null` will return Null.

Comment: OMG yeah I had one record that was empty. Thanks!